# Quantitative estimates on space filling curves

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems, fractals, billiards

To my understanding, quantitative topology/geometry makes statements quantitative. Examples: 1. a quantitative version of Invariance of Dimension is waist inequality. 2. Lusternik-Fet says a closed manifold has closed geodesic. A quantitative version is Gromov's systolic inequality.
I'm looking for analogous statements about space-filling curves/trees. For example, Peano curve fills in space in the limit, we can ask: how quickly does it fill in?

Let $I = [0, 1]^2$ be a unit square on the plane, and $\{ P_{i} \}_{i=1}^{N}$ denote Peano curve sequence up to step $N$. One way to say its speed of filling is to consider its $\epsilon$ perturbation: $\{ P_{i} + \epsilon \}_{i=1}^{N}$, by considering an $\epsilon$ tube around the curve. Now we can ask its volume growth by looking at the following area ratio sequence:
$$ r_{i} = \frac{Area(P_{i} + \epsilon)}{Area(I)}$$
Question 1: Fix $\epsilon$, what is the minimum number $N$ so that $P_{N}$ fills in all of $I$? Filling in means the ratio $r_{i} = 1$.

Question 2: What is the least $\epsilon_{i}$ to fill in $I$ for each $P_{i}$?

Question 3: What if we replace space filling curves/trees by billiard? What if we replace billiard by a random trajectory? By random trajectory, I mean a point is randomly initialise on $\partial I$, and it follows a  random velocity vector pointing towards the interior of $I$. When the particle hits the boundary, we repeat the random velocity vector process.